# Is an abstract method a normal instance method in a non-abstract class in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, abstract-class, abstract-methods, instance-methods

I defined **the abstract method `sound()`** with [**@abstractmethod**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#abc.abstractmethod) under **the non-abstract class `Animal`** which doesn't extend [**ABC**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#abc.ABC) and **`Cat` class** extends **`Animal` class**, then I could instantiate both **`Animal` and `Cat` classes** without any errors as shown below:

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class Animal: # Doesn't extend "ABC"
    @abstractmethod # Here
    def sound(self):
        print("Wow!!")

class Cat(Animal):
    pass

obj1 = Animal() # Here
obj1.sound()

obj2 = Cat() # Here
obj2.sound()
```

Output:

```
Wow!!
Wow!!
```

So, is **an abstract method** **a normal instance method** in **a non-abstract class** in Python?

Answer (score 4):

The `abstractmethod` decorator just adds some annotation to the method, which is evaluated by `ABC` when you try to instantiate the class. The method itself doesn't change in any way, it's still a regular instance method. It's the cooperation of `ABC` together with those `abstractmethod` decorator annotations that result in the desired behaviour of preventing instantiation of "abstract classes". It's not a concept enforced at the language level in any way, it's just layered on top of regular Python classes.